# get information from marker and use it in an intent

Tags: android, google-maps

I have markers on a map for particular restuarants. On these markers i have the phone numbers of these restuarants stored.In another activity which will be displayed when the user clicks on a particular marker there is a call icon on the default action bar. I would like my android application to take the phone number of the restuarant which the user would have clicked to be taken to the other activity and when the user clicks the call icon to automatically dial the number for that restaurant.Someone help...

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `onMarkerClick()` listener to your method. Here is an example:

```
public class MarkerInfoActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity implements OnMarkerClickListener
{
    private Marker myMarker;    

    private void setUpMap()
    {
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

        myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Restaurant 1")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

        if (marker.equals(myMarker)) 
        {
            // Intent to go to phone activity
        }
    }
}
```

You could have a array that stores all the information of that marker, and access it when that marker is clicked. When it is clicked, parse the number (and other values) to another Intent.

Comment: i have multiple markers so this method proves as a challenge

Comment: It could still work. Just put different cases in the `if` statement of `onMarkerClick()`.